# what is the parameter format for geometry.location?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

This is my function which contains the locations of the places i need to visit

```
 function callback() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="entered into callback function";
    var addresses = ['x','y','z'];
      for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
        createMarker(addresses[i]);
    }
  }
```

And this is my function for creating markers

```
function createMarker(place) {   
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+=" entered into createmarker function, location=";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+=place;
    var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML+="placeloc="+placeLoc;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });
```

in the page, i can see

```
entered into callback function entered into create marker function, location=x
```

but i cannot see the "placeloc=" sentence and alsp it's markers in the map, should x,y,z be in a particular format for geomtery.location to work?

Comment: Your addresses array members are strings. Strings don't have a `geometry` property.

Comment: okay? so what property should i convert the string to make it compatible?

Comment: the `.geometry.location` needs to be a `google.maps.LatLng` or a `google.maps.LatLngLiteral`. Where are your addresses coming from?  Where did your `createMarker` function come from?  (looks like it might have come from a Places API example in the google documentation) Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @geocodezip, as of now, the addresses come from a cell in my database table which contains locations of each user(provided by them in a textbox)
but in the forseeable future, i'll try making the user to pinpoint his location using google maps, but i'm having a hard time trying to return a place from  a marker to variable(which will then be used to store in the table)
Create marker function is calledby callback function(which is modified by me to fit my requirements)
Yes, this does come from Places API example

Answer (score 0):

To be used as the `position` property in a [`MarkerOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions)object:

`place.geometry.location` needs to be a [`google.maps.LatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)

A [`google.maps.LatLngLiteral`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngLiteral) should also work.

**code snippet (using a `google.maps.LatLngLiteral`):**

```js
var addresses = [
  {address: "New York, NY",geometry: {location: {lat: 40.7127837,lng: -74.0059413}}}, 
  {address: "Newark, NJ, USA",geometry: {location: {lat: 40.735657,lng: -74.1723667}}}, 
  {address: "Baltimore, MD, USA",geometry: {location: {lat: 39.2903848,lng: -76.6121893}}}, 
  {address: "Philadelphia, PA, USA",geometry: {location: {lat: 39.9525839,lng: -75.1652215}}}
];
var map;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  callback();

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

function callback() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "entered into callback function<br>";

  for (var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
    createMarker(addresses[i]);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function createMarker(place) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += " entered into createmarker function, location=";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += place + "<br>";
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += "placeloc=" + placeLoc.lat + "," + placeLoc.lng + "<br>";
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });
  bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```